# Why Besicovitch set has Minkowski dimension 2

Tags: measure-theory

A Besicovitch set is a set of measure $0$ containing line segments of length $1$ of every direction.

A bounded set has Minkowski dimension $\alpha$ if for every $\delta,\epsilon$, it can be covered by at most $C_{\epsilon}\delta^{-\alpha+\epsilon}$ balls of radius $\delta$.

How can we show that the Besicovitch set has Minkowski dimension 2?

Comment: I assume this is in dimension 2?

Comment: Yes, the Kayeya conjecture states that Besicovitch set in $R^d$ has full dimension $d$ and I want to verify the case for $R^2$